# IDE for Go capable of refactoring: variable, function, structure and package renaming

Tags: ide, go, refactoring, renaming, automated-refactoring

I am interested in any IDE (or even a script) that is capable of refactoring Go source code for variable renaming. For example in Eclipse for Java, one can select a variable, an object or a class, then to rename it and it gets automatically renamed in all the files in the project. This feature is very useful if automatic string replacement may cause substring collisions.

Comment: we are all waiting for something like it. There is a refactoring tool based on go oracle but is still not public yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're interested in a script, use [gofmt](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) with `-r` flag. Like this:

```
gofmt -w -r 'OldFoo -> Foo' foopackage
```

From the docs:

> Without an explicit path, it processes the standard input. Given a file, it operates on that file; given a directory, it operates on all .go files in that directory, recursively. (Files starting with a period are ignored.) By default, gofmt prints the reformatted sources to standard output.

**EDIT:** Today there are better tools for that: [gorename](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename) for renaming and [eg](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/eg) for general refactoring.

Comment: Doesn't this do simple string replacement? In that case it is not refactoring.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Since then the Go team has created a more precise tool called `gorename`. See veight's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [gorename](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename) tool performs precise type-safe renaming of identifiers in Go source code.